# SSH prompts password when deploying on remote server via Codeship

Tags: git, ssh, deployment, codeship

I am struggling with connection to my server via SSH through Codeship. I followed their docs but I cannot get it work.

So far I have completed all the steps to make it work but still no luck with it.

**Codeship Project SSH public key** - Added to my server's **authorized_keys** file

https://documentation.codeship.com/general/projects/project-ssh-key/

**Authenticating Via SSH Public Keys** - changed the permissions for the ssh folder with `chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh/`

https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/#authenticating-via-ssh-public-keys

Also I find out that other guys had the some problem:

https://community.codeship.com/t/what-is-password-for-ssh-access/995/6

... which btw I followed but still with no luck. I've run:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

... to get my server public key and added it to my Personal Account Settings in Codeship.

Finally I added this test command to my Custom Script in the project's **Deploy** section.

```
ssh user@domain.com 'mkdir test_folder'
```

So after I made some build with `git push` this is what I get i.e. the script is prompted with password enter:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'domain.com,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@domain.com's password:
```

Any idea what could be the problem, or what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show us how you've set things up, rather than just claiming you followed the steps described in some tutorial.

Comment: @Kenster what else you want me to provide? So far I've:

- connected my repo to the Codeship project
- managed to use the lftp command to update the project when git push ( a build ) is running.
- lftp takes too much time because it takes all changes and copies all files one by one ( one build can take up to 30mins )
- decided to go with ssh to log into my server and CD to my directory to run git pull 
- cannot do that because the script is prompted with passowrd ( I already posted the script code above where I try to connect via SSH

Comment: Ahoy @Ivica, just to summarize, you added the projects public SSH Key (from the projects _General_ settings page) to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file your server. But you can't connect from an automated build, or a debug VM for that matter? Are you able to connect via SSH from your local machine? And did you run a ssh command in (very) verbose mode via `ssh -vvv ...` This will spit out a lot of log output, but also include pointers on why the key is not accepted.

Comment: @mlocher 

Sorry for the late reply. I solved the problem later and the SSH command for connection to my server is now working via codeship but only for one project.

I Created setup another separate project and repeated the steps:

1. Added the project ssh-rsa key to my server
2. Tried to connect to the other project via SSH on the SAME server but did not succeed. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here!